# Laptop not waking up from suspend (plugged-in) since 14.10 upgrade

Tags: suspend, 14.10

Ever since I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.10, my laptop is failing to wake up from suspend mode ONLY when charger is plugged in. When I have the charger plugged in, no matter how many times I hard-restart by pressing power button, laptop will not wake up- it hangs on a blank screen. When I unplug the charger, only then the laptop reboots successfully. 
Anyone know what's going on here? Similar problems anyone? I haven't had this problem prior to 14.10 upgrade. It's really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my issue is the same as yours, but I experience something similar on my Lenovo T440 running Ubuntu 14.10. After I leave my desk for a while, I come back, the screen is blank and doesn't come back to life when I move the mouse or press keys.

I found that going in to one of the terminal screens (i.e. CTRL + ALT + F1) and then back to the Unity screen (i.e. CTRL + ALT + F7) brings the login screen back.

Answer (score 0):

I too am having an issue since 14.10, or more so, after some weird upgrade I can't even find (the computer won't even tell me what upgrade it did).  I filed a bug report here:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1389300